# Magento 2 one page checkout enabled but still multipage checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

I have enabled the one page checkout in Magento 2 but still my checkouts are multipage. What should I do to more than setting enabled under stores-sales-checkout options in the Enable Onepage Checkout    box?

Magento 2.1.8

Thanks

Comment: Just commenting to say that Magento 2 is outrageously bad. The fact that its "onepage checkout" actually has two pages is a perfect metaphor for the entire application. If you're a developer thinking about using Magento 2, don't. Don't use it. Run away from it screaming and set it on fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento default settings

```
Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Enable Onepage Checkout >> Yes.
```

This options by default enabled, it is showing 2 steps checkout with one page not one step.

If you need to one step checkout, you need to install 3rd party extension for one step checkout.

**Note :** One step and one page both are different, Magento give only one page checkout not one step.

Comment: At my end, checkout is multipage(shipping and payment) even if the setting is enabled. please help.